# Where can I get started learning about Rule Engines?

Tags: java, rule-engine

I'm currently designing a Java application where a Rule engine could be useful.  Where is a good place I can learn about how to use them, how they work, how to implement them, see samples, etc.?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Drools [documentation](http://www.drools.org/learn/documentation.html) includes a lot of useful, general purpose information. Especially chapter 2, which covers rule engine basics, knowledge representation, etc. It also includes a nice recommended reading list for coming up to speed on rule engines and expert systems.

For most rule engines, a basic understanding of the [rete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm) algorithm usually comes in handy for writing efficient rules. I have personally found the [Doorenbos](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/1995/CMU-CS-95-113.pdf) paper referenced in the Wikipedia article to be the clearest technical explanation.

Also, [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/rule-engines) is a list of open source rule engines in Java.

Comment: Ah thanks for the Rete article.  I've been trying to find a good article to help wrap my brain around that.

Comment: Nice answer. Got trigged to find a .Net impementation of Rete and Drools http://droolsdotnet.codehaus.org/ +1

Comment: Thanks. For every Java project, it seems there's a .Net implementation not far behind ... poor Java :)

Comment: @Keb - About 3 years ago I used NxBRE for a .NET project. https://sourceforge.net/projects/nxbre/. Nothing fancy but it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to read "[Should I use a Rules Engine?](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RulesEngine.html)" from Martin Fowler's blog.

I have worked on a project where we built our own (very simple) rules engine, with the intention to move to a general rule engine when things got too complicated. Never reached that point though, the system has been running happily with the simple homegrown engine for several years now.

Comment: I highly recommend that entry as well -- correlates well with my experiences.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this site](http://ai-depot.com/Tutorial/RuleBased.html) pretty helpful. Are you looking at building your own, or using a 3rd party library?

Comment: I'd consider building my own if it helped me learn how to use them better in some way.  Otherwise a third party one ought to be fine.